# Difference in array initialization method and storage pattern in memory

Tags: ada

I am new to Ada programming, So had few doubts in array initialization which I could not get across. Please let me know your inputs:

```ada
type Faults_db is
  record
    Det_bits    : Integer_16;
    Det_faults  : Faults_set.Set_init_type(1..12); 
  end record;

type Faults_db_array is array (Fault_types.Fault_mode_Type) of Faults_db;
```

While initializing Det_faults, whether the initialization options shown below will result same or any different in storage pattern:

```ada
Det_faults => Faults_set.Set_init_type'(1..1 => Fault_types.FAULT_1),
```

OR

```ada
Det_faults => Faults_set.Set_init_type'(Fault_types.FAULT_1),
```

Similarly whether these Initialization below are same, please comment.

```ada
Detected_mask => Faults_set.Set_init_type'(1 => Fault_types.Fault_1,
                                       2 => Fault_types.Fault_2,
                                       3..12 => Fault_types.Fault_3)

OR
```

```ada
Detected_mask => Faults_set.Set_init_type'(Fault_types.Fault_1,
                                       Fault_types.Fault_2,
                                       others => Fault_types.Fault_3)
```

As per my understanding from various Ada resources, both should be same because while declaring I am mentioning as range for `Det_faults  : Faults_set.Set_init_type(1..12);`  But, wanted to know if there are any differences.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For completeness, you should show us the definition of `Faults_set.Set_init_type`.

Comment: While your question is about initialization, it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. The code fragments you show contain significant syntax errors. Can you post something that compiles without errors or warnings?

Answer (score 2):

```
Det_faults => Faults_set.Set_init_type'(1..1 => Fault_types.FAULT_1),
OR
Det_faults => Faults_set.Set_init_type'(Fault_types.FAULT_1),
```

Neither of these will compile, because `Det_faults` is an array with 12 elements.

```
Detected_mask => Faults_set.Set_init_type'(1 => Fault_types.Fault_1,
                                           2 => Fault_types.Fault_2,
                                           3..12 => Fault_types.Fault_3)

OR

Detected_mask => Faults_set.Set_init_type'(Fault_types.Fault_1,
                                           Fault_types.Fault_2,
                                           others => Fault_types.Fault_3)
```

These will have the same effect (assuming, that is, that when you say `Detected_mask` you mean `Det_faults`).